# SQLite query SQLiteLog (1) no such Column:

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I have 3 classes. 
One to setup the DB and tables, works fine. `DBHelper.java`

```
private static final String TAG = "DBHelper";
public static final String DB_NAME = "pat_test.db";
public static final String TABLE5 = "sites";
public static final String S_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
public static final String S_CLIENT = "client_of_site";
public static final String S_POSTCODE = "site_postode";
public static final String S_CON_NAME = "contact_name";
public static final String S_CON_NUM = "contact_tel_num";
public static final String S_NAME = "site_name";
public static final String S_LAST_TEST = "last_test_date";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


String sql5 = String.format("create table %s (%s INT PRIMARY KEY, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s INT, %s TEXT)",TABLE5, S_ID, S_CLIENT, S_NAME, S_POSTCODE, S_CON_NAME,S_CON_NUM,S_LAST_TEST); 
Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: " + sql5);
db.execSQL(sql5);
}
```

The next one has my functions `DBControl.java`

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;    
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public class DBControl {

public static final String TABLE5 = "sites";

public static final String S_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
public static final String S_CLIENT = "client_of_site";
public static final String S_NAME = "site_name";
public static final String S_POSTCODE = "site_postode";
public static final String S_CON_NAME = "contact_name";
public static final String S_CON_NUM = "contact_tel_num";
public static final String S_LAST_TEST = "last_test_date";

private Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private DBHelper dbhelper;

public DBControl(Context context) {

    this.context = context;

}

  public DBControl open() throws SQLiteException {

    dbhelper = new DBHelper(context);
    database = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {

    dbhelper.close();

}
   public ContentValues createContentValues3(String CLIENT, 
        String NAME,    String POSTCODE, String CON_NAME, 
         long CON_NUM) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(S_CLIENT, CLIENT);
    values.put(S_POSTCODE, POSTCODE);
    values.put(S_CON_NAME, CON_NAME);
    values.put(S_CON_NUM, CON_NUM);
    values.put(S_NAME, NAME);
    return values;
  }  
   public long addSiteDetails( String CLIENT, String NAME,
        String POSTCODE, String CON_NAME, int CON_NUM ) {

    ContentValues siteValues = createContentValues3( CLIENT, NAME,
            POSTCODE, CON_NAME, CON_NUM );

    return database.insert(TABLE5, null, siteValues);
}


public boolean updateSiteDetails(long id, String CLIENT, String NAME,
        String POSTCODE, String CON_NAME , int CON_NUM
        ) {

    ContentValues siteUpdateValues = createContentValues3( CLIENT, NAME,
            POSTCODE, CON_NAME, CON_NUM);

    return database.update(TABLE5, siteUpdateValues, S_ID + "=" + id, null) > 0;
}

}
  public long fetchSiteIdByName(String NAME){

     Cursor dbCursor; 
     long id = 0;

      try { 

     dbCursor = database.query(true, TABLE5, new String []{S_ID}, S_NAME + "= " + NAME  , null, null, null, null, null);
     dbCursor.moveToFirst(); 
     id = dbCursor.getLong(dbCursor.getColumnIndex(S_ID)); } 

      catch (SQLiteException e) { 

          id = -1;

      }

      return id;

      }
```

My third class is used to call and check. But this is where my problem arises or in fetchSiteIdByName in the previous class.

```
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.app.Dialog;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  public class activityStartNewTest extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button buttonBeginTesting;
private AutoCompleteTextView clientInput;       //Refers to input box for client
private AutoCompleteTextView siteInput;         //Refers to input box for site
private AutoCompleteTextView postcodeInput;     //Refers to input box for postcode
private EditText nameInput;                     //Refers to input box for contact name
private EditText telInput;                      //Refers to input box for contact number
  //    private EditText jobrefInput;                   //Refers to input box for Job reference number

private DBControl dbControl;                

@ Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start_new_test);
    dbControl = new DBControl(this);
    clientInput = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteClientNameEdit);
    siteInput = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteSiteNameEdit);
    postcodeInput = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompletePostcodeEdit);
    nameInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextContactName);
    telInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextContactNum);
  //        jobrefInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextJobRef);      

    buttonBeginTesting = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBeginTesting);
    buttonBeginTesting.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


public void onClick(View arg) {

    String clientData = clientInput.getText().toString();
    String siteData = siteInput.getText().toString();
    String postcodeData = postcodeInput.getText().toString();
    String nameData = nameInput.getText().toString();
    String telData = telInput.getText().toString();
     // String jobrefData = jobrefInput.getText().toString();

    Toast toastNotice = new Toast(this);
    Dialog notice = new Dialog(this); // this needs the textview below for displaying
    TextView msgBody = new TextView(this);
    msgBody.setTextSize(20);
    long tempValue = 0;

    switch(arg.getId()){

    case R.id.buttonBeginTesting:

    try{
        int telDataAsNum = Integer.parseInt(telData);
        dbControl.open();

        if((tempValue = dbControl.fetchSiteIdByName(siteData)) != -1) {

            if(dbControl.updateSiteDetails(tempValue, clientData, siteData, postcodeData, nameData, telDataAsNum)){
                notice.setTitle("Site Updated!");
                msgBody.setText("Site detail have been updated instead");
            }
            else{
                notice.setTitle("Update failed!");
                msgBody.setText("Site already Exists, but failed!");
            }
        }
        else{
            long siteID = 0;

            siteID = dbControl.addSiteDetails( clientData, siteData, postcodeData, nameData, telDataAsNum );
            notice.setTitle("Site Added");
            msgBody.setText("Site added at row "+ siteID);
    }
    dbControl.close();

    }
    catch (SQLiteException e){ // Notifies user if SQL error occurred
        e.printStackTrace();
        notice.setTitle("Insert failed");
        msgBody.setText("SQL Error!");
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e){ // Notifies user if NUM format error occurred
        e.printStackTrace();
        notice.setTitle("Insert failed");
        msgBody.setText("Contact number must be a number!");
    }
    notice.setContentView(msgBody);
    notice.show();
  }
  }
  }
```

Now when I run the application I insert into the DB with new details absolutley fine. 
Using adb I pull the DB and open in sqlite3. It shows all entries with NULL in the first column and NULL in the last (the last has not been posted yet).
I use the same text in the field of the editbox siteData and it just adds a new entry and does not update the previous.

The log cat is showing SQLiteLog (1) no such column: xxx where xxx would have been the entry into the autocompleteTextView.

Why is it looking for a column named to whatever text was input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears I had 3 different issues but using Lokesh's links and post's help me get a fix.

I modified the SQL string in DBelper.java to this

```
   String sql5 = String.format("create table %s (%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY **AUTOINCREMENT**, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s INT, %s TEXT)",
                    TABLE5, S_ID, S_CLIENT, S_NAME, S_POSTCODE, S_CON_NAME,
                    S_CON_NUM, S_LAST_TEST);
```

And added to the DBControl.java class

```
  **if**(dbCursor.moveToFirst()) id = dbCursor.getLong(dbCursor.getColumnIndex(S_ID));
```

Dropping the semicolon after the moveToFirst()). Like I said I'm a real noob but believe this to be correct.

Adding the AUTOINCREMENT had 1 dramatic effect when I uninstalled and reinstalled the application (I could have changed the DB version instead, if I wanted too, I know).

When the Tables were rebuilt they did not have the column _id I had seen before. So I think the SQL string was the reason for my failure. I'm sure I heard somewhere it wasn't required for PRIMARY KEY basecolumns._ID but now I know IT IS.

Thanks Lokesh for your pointers. I couldn't have found the issue without some guidance and I really appreciate it.

I tried to add to the up arrow but don't have enough rating yet. Doh.

Hope this helps others.

Comment: This Link also really helped.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573985/error-android-database-cursorindexoutofboundsexception-index-0-requested-wit

Answer (score 2):

Surrounding the NAME in fetchSiteIdByName() with single quotes might help.

```
dbCursor = database.query(true, TABLE5, new String []{S_ID}, S_NAME + "= '" + NAME + "'"  , null, null, null, null, null);
```

I'm not much sure if it will work on SQLite but I've been through same kind of issues in MySQL and it helps. Moreover, when you fetch non-numeric values in the database you surround them in single quotes.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: I tried to add the single and the double quote, single quote, double quote but it returned the error caught in the last class

else{ notice.setTitle("Update failed!"); msgBody.setText("Site already Exists, but failed!"); 

when it was a duplicate entry, with the same error in logcat as above "no such column: 

Then just crashed out with a new entry? 

E/AndroidRuntime(3835): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Comment: Yup, and I think you should check this as it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316336/cursor-index-out-of-bounds-index-0-requested-with-size-0